# Spring Data JPA Dependency Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a project with Spring and PostgreSQL. When I add the JPA dependencies, the project just break.

**The message error is:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.stringHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at minibagsbolsas.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@42110406]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:559) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:156) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted }
```

I already tested with another Spring Data JPA versions, but still not working.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` - looks like a missing dependency or classpath error.  Without more information it's unlikely someone here can help.

Comment: Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the dependency management from Spring boot (like overriding versions, including individual dependencies next to the starter etc.). You are using Spring Boot 3, which is JakartaEE and you are probably including an older API v ersion or hibernate. Please include your pom or build file so we can check what is wrong (and cleanup your dependencies).

Comment: Did anyone find solution for this. Below are the dependencies:
Using:- JDK 8.

Spring Boot - 2.7.12,
Hibernate - 5.6.15.Final,
Hibernate Validator - 6.2.5.Final,
Spring Boot Starter Data JPA - 2.7.12
Note: pom.xml has dependency for persistence api coming from two jars:

javax.persistence.api[2.2] - hibernate core - 5.6.15.Final,
jakarta.persistence.api[2.2.3] - spring boot starter data jpa ,